# Using the Android Gallery as an automated slideshow

Tags: java, android, timer, components, gallery

Hi I want to create a splashscreen for an app, and have a gallery rotate several images on a timer. Can anyone show me how I could use a timer to animate the images in a Gallery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

an easy solution would be

```
private int PicPosition;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

...
...
...

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        myslideshow();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);\\execute every second.
    }
};

    private void myslideshow()
    {
                    PicPosition = gallery.getSelectedItemPosition() +1;             
                    if (PicPosition >=  Pictures.size())            
                    PicPosition =  gallery.getSelectedItemPosition(); //stop 
                                    else
                    gallery.setSelection(PicPosition);//move to the next gallery element.
    }
```