# Create a slideshow with ImageViewe - Android

Tags: android, arrays, animation, imageview

I need to know how to create a slideshow of images using a ImageView, the names of image files are loaded from an array. So far I have tried this:

```
for(i=0;i<bL.length;i++){

imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
a = new TranslateAnimation(
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
a.setDuration(5000);

imgView.startAnimation(a);

}
```

But only managed to load the last image of the array, not seeing themselves full animation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you looked at the Gallery widget?

Comment: surely imageview only holds one image at a time! This SO answer might be of help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373536/using-the-android-gallery-as-an-automated-slideshow/3376203#3376203

Comment: Are trying to continously slide a group of images?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Gallery Wigdet for this particular project.